# Guymager Device disconnected, acquisition paused

Tags: usb, disk-image

An external SD card is connected to Precise Penguin via USB. The device mounts and is recognized by guymager. Image cloning commences for a few seconds with data transferred but then the process halts with the following error:

Device disconnected, acquisition paused

This happens repeatedly. The physical connection is solid, I believe. Perhaps the device dismounts for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

It means, that the device disappears from the list of known devices. This normally is due to hardware problems.

I saw this problem several times with harddisks. They sometimes "disconnect", "switch off", "hang" or whatever you may want to call it when reading certain bad sectors.

Guymager has a special feature that might help you to recover from such a problem - with a bit of luck:

- Connect the device, preferably via USB or ESATA. Start the acquisition and wait until the device switches to "disconnected"
- Unplug the device data and power cables (therefore USB or ESATA)
- Wait a moment, re-plug the device, wait another 5 seconds or so
- Press <kbd>Rescan</kbd> in Guymager (or <kbd>F5</kbd>). If the device came back to life, the acquisition should continue at the point it paused.

You may try the procedure with a good device first. That way, you can get a feeling for the whole procedure. Take an USB stick for example. Simply unplug the stick somewhere in the middle of the acquisition and you'll get "disconnected"; try the replug procedure then.

Good luck!